# XSL FO different footer for every page

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I need to add a picture with encoded page number info on footer of every page. I know I could make multiple page sequences (more than 20 in this case) with different footers, but is there any way to do this with just 1 page sequence?
My first idea was multiple ifs in region-after definition, something like:

```
if page-number = 1
then page1.png
if page-number = 2
then page2.png
```

etc., but the way `<fo:page-number/>` works is that I can't use it like a normal number variable, so do you have any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: You cannot use logic on numbering as it is not resolved at that point. If you know where pages will be you could use markers or footnotes. Otherwise you can postprocess the area tree to inject them

Comment: There is several ways to do what you wish, but you should provide more information for us to suggest. I can list several solutions that do what you want but some are pure FO with limitations, others are postprocessing things.

A few keys are .. do you know where page breaks in the XSL maybe (because you use page-break and you know everything is one page) ... or do you pre know how many pages? 

Or just that you want simple flowing content where every page footer is different and have no idea?

Comment: Do you mean 'multiple page sequences' or 'multiple `fo:simple-page-master`'?